# Destroy browser session for current url using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, session, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I am trying to login to gmail using my extension , this functionality is working fine, when session is already present in browser and i try login using extension , my extension authentication (using some jquery) method doesn't work.
I want to destroy the session for current url if session exists

Comment: cant we do something like clearing the browser session for particular url using javascript

Comment: Even if you clear the browser session, its not a good approach. You should destroy the session on the server side from the security perspective.

Answer (score 3):

You can do one thing, if you know the cookie variable, you can delete the cookie which is holding the session data, so when the URL is hit, it will check for the session data, which is now deleted and your code would work fine.

$.removeCookie("cookieName");

Answer (score 1):

Sessions are maintained on server and could not removed on client without sending request to server.

You can do it will ajax call at most or use postback to remove the sessions.

Or you can fire url appending timestamp at the end of your URL in ajax call so it will consider as new request.

Comment: cant we do something like clearing the browser session for particular url using javascript

Comment: no you have to call server using ajax for destroying the session without Server side you cannot